# Twitter IFRAME gets lost when I use appendTo on parent

Tags: jquery, iframe, responsive-design, appendto

I have a scenario in a widgetized WordPress page where I originally load all the content in a single column made up of six individual widgets.

When the browser window is >= 768 pixels, I then create two columns:

- Main Column:  divs #1-4, in order
- Sidebar: div #6 followed by div #5

In order to reflow the document this way and because I'm using a lot of dynamic content, I've been using jQuery's `appendTo` in the following way:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var w = $(window).width();

  $(window).on('load resize', adjustFlow);

  function adjustFlow() {
      if (w >= 768 ) {
          $('#div1').appendTo('#main');
          $('#div2').appendTo('#main');
          $('#div6').appendTo('#sidebar');
           $('#div5').appendTo('#sidebar');
        } else {
           $('#div5').appendTo('#div4');
           $('#div6').appendTo('#div5');
        }
     };

  }); /* end of as page load scripts */
```

(NOTE:  I don't apply `appendTo` on divs #3&4 because I'm using CSS media-queries to just get them to float the right way at the end of everything else.)

The jQuery is working as expected. However, div #6 includes the basic Twitter timeline embed ([docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines)) using the basic code provided by Twitter (i.e., I'm not rolling my own custom query or anything).

When the browser window is less than 768px and everything stays in one column, the Twitter timeline shows up...but the moment things start to shift around, I get an empty div where my timeline should be. I'm assuming the moving about is making Twitter's IFRAME unhappy and tried to force the IFRAME to refresh after everything else ran by adding

`$('#twitter-widget-1').attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; });`

after both the `if` and `else` statements...but no change in behavior.

Am I likely right that the `appendTo` and IFRAME aren't playing nice? Any idea of what I can do to get the IFRAME to keep up with my shuffling div?

EDIT AFTER MORE TIME WORKING ON THIS: Is there a way to either make the jQuery reshuffling wait until the IFRAME has loaded OR make the IFRAME loading wait until after the jQuery reshuffling? Also, the IFRAME content is loaded from off my domain (since it's coming from Twitter) and appears to use a sandbox, if that effects any answers.

Comment: Could you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the nudge, Alvaro; yes, I did finally sort things out! I used the following code:

```
if ($('#tweets iframe').length) {
         $('#tweets iframe').remove();
         callTwitter();
      } else {
         callTwitter();
      }
   };
```

I added the above to my original `adjustFlow` function (in production, btw, I didn't have numbered DIVs so #div6 = #tweets). The following is the new function referenced in the above code:

```
   function callTwitter() {
      $('<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/YrUSERNAME" data-widget-id="YrWIDGETID">Tweets</a>').appendTo('#tweets .textwidget');
      twttr.widgets.load();
   };
```

I expect this is not the most friendly answer in terms of page load time, etc., but I also think resizing the browser to end up with this issue is likely an edge case scenario for most users. Also note that some of the specifics of this (e.g., the 'textwidget` class in  the function above) are WordPress workarounds and wouldn't be necessary or would be replaced in other situations.